# overflow: hidden of my div is allowing my window height to be truly 100% when it shouldn't be

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to CSS and I did what I intended to do, which is to make my window width and height 100% for a div so it fills up my window. However, what I am confused about is that I had to add:

```
    .myDiv{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAATklEQVQYV2NkYGAwZmBgOMuAACA+CKCIMSIpADGRNaEYgKwQ3WQUjTCF6CYhWw2WAynEpgjmIpg7jUlSiM0TWK2GWUOUZ7ApxggeogIcABHJFtfoX9tJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
   ) repeat;
}
```

When I didn't add `overflow: hidden;`I got a little bit of whitespace above myDiv, which is the first div of my html. To avoid this, I came across overflow:hidden but the idea of overflow: hidden is that the content of the div should be clipped. However, in my case, the content of myDiv is expanded to cover the whitespace after adding `overflow:hidden;` Why is that so?

Comment: Have you reset the ``body` default margin?

Answer (score 2):

margin of body element is set to 8px that is why..

With vw and vh: (not fully supported) see [can i use vieuwport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>MAGIC</div>
```

<strike>with % height is not affected on block elements:</strike>
Eumz width is 100% on block element no need to define it again

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>MAGIC</div>
```

Edit: final

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAATklEQVQYV2NkYGAwZmBgOMuAACA+CKCIMSIpADGRNaEYgKwQ3WQUjTCF6CYhWw2WAynEpgjmIpg7jUlSiM0TWK2GWUOUZ7ApxggeogIcABHJFtfoX9tJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
) repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>MAGIC</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **`* { margin : 0; }`** in the beginning.

Here is the snippet.

```css
* {
  margin : 0;
}
.myDiv {
  position : absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAATklEQVQYV2NkYGAwZmBgOMuAACA+CKCIMSIpADGRNaEYgKwQ3WQUjTCF6CYhWw2WAynEpgjmIpg7jUlSiM0TWK2GWUOUZ7ApxggeogIcABHJFtfoX9tJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class='myDiv'></div>
```

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, but using *  is very bad just use body instead (causes lags in some cases)

Answer (score 0):

All browsers have set padding or margin around the edge of the web page so as to not have text right next to the screen.

You also don't need to use the `overflow: hidden` property if you use `vw` and `vh` which specify to be 100% of the viewport height/width.

This needs to be reset in your CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.myDiv {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAATklEQVQYV2NkYGAwZmBgOMuAACA+CKCIMSIpADGRNaEYgKwQ3WQUjTCF6CYhWw2WAynEpgjmIpg7jUlSiM0TWK2GWUOUZ7ApxggeogIcABHJFtfoX9tJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
) repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

- [Viewport Units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)